# Selected navigation item is invisible in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, invisible, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have created `MainActivity` with `Navigation Drawer` with five different activities. When I click on one activity it opens associated activity layout. After pressing back button, it goes to `MainActivity`.

Problem is that the selected activity/item's name is `invisible` in `Navigation Drawer` but onClick is working. Please help me.
Here is my code

```
 package com.cabbi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("RIDE NOW"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("RIDE LATER"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabsAdapter=new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_myrides) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyRides.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyProfile.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_promotions) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Promotions.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_changepassword) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResetPassword.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: i think it's transparent. try to set backgroud/text color.

Comment: Thanks for replay, i will try it and let u know

Comment: Please also post xml file...

Comment: FYI NavigationDrawer is to be used with Fragment not Activity

Comment: we can use activities also instead of fragments  but fragment is the best approch,i agree with your answer@josemigallas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this below property to `NavigationView`.

```
 app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
 app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
```

you can use your own color here. i use `white color` like this way  `@android:color/white`.

**full code :**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#0072BA"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you  **colorAccent,colorPrimary** to some visible color

Change the color in  android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

> **app:itemIconTint="#000"
>       app:itemTextColor="#000"**